# purify on Suse Linux

Tags: suse, purify

I am having trouble running Purify on Suse Linux. Here are the version details:

```
/apps/purifyplus_7.0.1/releases/purify.i386_linux2.7.0.1/purify -version
Version 7.0.1 091008 Linux

cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)
VERSION = 10
PATCHLEVEL = 2
```

When I run my application under Purify (turned on -verbose option ), I see the following:

```
Purify/PureCoverage engine: VERBOSE_INFO: Reallocing block 1 (0 80)
Linking
Purify: forkexec(/usr/bin/ld, [/usr/bin/ld --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 someFiles)
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
run purify  ... 
/bin/ksh: line 1: /.log: cannot create [Permission denied]
gmake[3]: [runPurify] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Can somebody tell me what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with the make file